# Where are the tab-settings in Notepad++ newer versions?

Tags: notepad++

Where are the tab-settings in Notepad++ newer versions?

Some old documentation talks about `Settings > Preferences > Tab Settings`, but I find no such section.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of 2016 these were moved to:

```
Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings.
```

Comment: `Einstellungen > Optionen > Sprache > Tabulatorbreite`

Comment: As of Jun 17 2021 v8.1, these are still there.

Comment: Just checked on July 17, 2023 v8.4.6 this is still true

Answer (score 3):

As @JohnDoea discovered in Answering his own Question, indeed `Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings` is where to find tab settings. I was about to refute what he said when I finally noticed the easily-overlooked (at least by me), tiny area at lower right of that window. If you click whatever's underlined (for me it was 2), you get a dialog box where you can change `Tab Size`.

[image]

Note that under `Tab Settings` is the option `normal`, which produces the following window, in which there is a way to set the default tab size:

[image]

Using version 7.5.6.

Before composing this Answer, I wasn't familiar with the new location setup for tabs. I don't recall where it used to be, but it wasn't as hard to find as it was for John and me.

Upon further consideration, I guess this is as good a place as any for tab settings.

But a suggestion: instead of having to know to look at the `Language` option in the first listbox to find `Tabs`, add `Tabs` to the list box and let its selection also bring you to the window above.

And another: add a way to get to tab settings by modifying `View > Tab` (below) to also bring up the window above.

[image]